# How can I simplify query to avoid multiple trips to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How can I avoid multiple calls to repositories and simplify using joins?

```
var members = await _groupMemberRepository.Value.GetAllGroupMembers(groupId);
var groupMemberModels = members as IGroupMemberModel[] ?? members.ToArray();
var users = await _userManager.Value.GetUsersList(groupMemberModels.Select(x => x.UserId));
var roles = await _userAccountBusinessLogic.GetRoles(null);
return (from m in groupMemberModels
    join u in users
        on m.UserId equals u.Id
    select
        new Member
        {
            UserId = m.UserId,
            FirstName = u.FirstName,
            LastName = u.LastName,
            Username = u.UserName,
            GroupUserType = m.GroupUserType,
            LastLoggedIn = u.LastLoggedIn,
            Roles = MeeRoleParser.ParseList(u.Roles.Select(x =>
                roles.Where(r => r.Id == x.RoleId).Select(r => r.Name).FirstOrDefault()).ToList())
        }).ToArray();
```

The above query calls different repositories. I am not getting an idea how to do a join and simplify the call

Comment: Each `FirstOrDefault` type call (includes `First`, `Single`, etc) that returns an actual object instead of an `IQueryable` will be sending a Database request, unless you have already made that query and have caching enabled.  In situations like this, I find it easier to write a view that does this logic on the database side and returns only the data I need in a new model. Can you tag what your ORM is? (I assume you use one, such as Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc.)

Comment: ORM is Entity framework

Comment: You have just discovered one reason why you don't want each entity managed by a separate repository.  Your DbContext should have `DbSet<T>` properties for each entity, and can be used to join across them, or traverse related entities using eager or lazy loading.

Comment: In addition to what @ps2goat identified regarding FirstOrDefault, any `ToList()`, `ToArray()` etc will cause linq to evaluate the query there and you no longer have an expression but data that is fetched.